# hostname and /etc/hosts

Tags: server, email, postfix, hostname

I intend to purchase a domain, say for instance `muppets.org`, for my web server and I would like to install Postfix on the same machine for sending transactional emails. 
Am I expected to set as hostname for my system `muppets.org`, or I can use as hostname `kermit`, so that my FQDN can be `kermit.muppets.org`?
According to [Digital Ocean's documentation on Postfix](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04), my server's hostname should match my domain, `muppets.org`: is that necessary or instead I can use as hostname `kermit` and edit `/etc/hosts` as follows?

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain           localhost
127.0.1.1       kermit.muppets.org              kermit
198.51.100.3    kermit.muppets.org              kermit
```

Comment: This is a networking question that has nothing to do with Ubuntu (or any OS). Your DNS provider cares deeply about your FQDN (that's their job), but cares nothing about the system hostname. They will direct all DNS lookup requests to a specific IP address, regardless of the hostname at that IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the name that you assign to your computer (hostname), what will define whether or not it is in a subdomain will be the public DNS server (bind, for example) and not the /etc/hosts file, which only affects the requests of your local network.
You can manage the subdomains on your Resource Records A, AAAA, CNAME, MX, TXT, PTR, SRV.

Note that one of the prerequisites of that article is "A valid domain name, like example.com, pointing to your server."

You can use `kermit.muppets.org` since you point the DNS server to that VPS server. Another approach is to set a reverse proxy to point to the resource you want.

Check out a more detailed explanation here: https://serverfault.com/questions/507103/hostname-or-subdomain